# <table> <table> in Flex Apps

Tags: html, flash, apache-flex, html-table, alignment

I am learning flex and have written a little app with a TextArea that had data getting populated dynamically by embedding simple HTML (mostly for font styles)

I ran into a weird issue when I wanted to include images, the images in this case are small arrows as in reddit.com. My desired aligmnent is,

```
-------------
 o | foo bar
   | ffdfdfdf
   | fdfd
-------------
 o | dfdd
-------------
```

Where o in the first column is an image. Note that the borders are invisible.
I just used a simple `<Table></table>` and works perfectly if I view the resulting HTML in a browser. However flash renders the table in a very screwed manner, I get something like this instead

```
--------------
 o   fooooooo
 ffffdfdf
 fdfd
-------------
 o   fff
--------------
```

If the second line has more than one line, the subsequent lines wrap around the first column. Is this a known problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash's (and hence Flex's) [htmlText](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText) doesn't officially support tables to begin with.

Use a [Datagrid](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/DataGrid.html) instead.